# Unable to install Visual Studio Tools for Applications from Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007

Tags: ms-office, vsta

When going to 'Add or Remove Features ' > Microsoft Office > Microsoft Office Infopath > .NET Programmability Support > .NET Programmability support for .NET Framework version 2.0 > Visual Studio Tools for Applications (set this to "Run from my computer"), I get message, **Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007 configuration did not complete successfully**.  I have the prerequisites installed so I'm not sure the reason VSTA won't install.  Does anyone have any idea?  I have not found any information regarding this particular issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the required .Net framework version installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes.  I have v2.0, v3.0, v3.5, and v4.0.  Does that make a difference that I have multiple .NET versions?  Also, one other requirement that must be installed is Microsoft Core XML Services 6.0.  I downloaded this from the internet but that did not work.  Would this service have already been installed on my machine?  If so, where?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem for Office Professional Plus 2007!
I have xml core 6 pre installed and ticked .net 2.0 in this very installation window.
a typically microsoft error message, only meaningless b*****it

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got mine to work now. i simply uninstalled InfoPath by changing
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007 installation in appwiz.cpl (Programs & Features).

When running the Office Setup again i selected every package below InfoPath
[image]

(sorry for the screenshot beeing in german but i rly didn't get the installation wizard to change it's language, i tried everything.)

Hope it works for you.
cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Everyone.  I just ended up uninstalling MS 2007 and installing MS 2013.  I did this because other issues came up with MS 2007.